# Como evitar mostrar en una webview la blank page que contiene un video?

Tags: android

Estoy interesado en mostrar solamente el video de una url mediante `webview` y me gustaria deshacerme de la página en blanco, que aparece al salir del video en fullscreen.

**NO USO** `<iframe>` para mostrar el video. ¿hay alguna manera? Os dejo foto del problema

[image]

Gracias por adelantado.

A continuacion añado mi codigo:

**WebViewActivity.java**

```
    private VideoEnabledWebView webView;
    private VideoEnabledWebChromeClient webChromeClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        View nonVideoLayout = findViewById (R.id.nonVideoLayout);
        ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.videoLayout);
        View loadingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_loading_video, null);
        webView = (VideoEnabledWebView) findViewById (R.id.webView);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
            getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }

webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout, loadingView, webView)
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                // TODO
            }
        };
        webChromeClient.setOnToggledFullscreen(new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.ToggledFullscreenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {
                if (fullscreen) {
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

        if (urlConElVideo != null) {
            webView.loadUrl(urlConElVideo);}

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, para poder ayudarte mejor, por favor muestranos lo que **si** estas haciendo. [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Acabo de añadirlo, gracias por el interes

Comment: ¿La url Es directamente al video o a un html que contiene el video?¿tienes control sobre la página que se carga en el webview? Si sí, ¿podrías compartir el código también?

Comment: La url es directamente a una pagina que es un reproductor de un video, como por ejemplo rutube o youtube. Como no me interesa usar las API's, lo querria usar de esta manera, lo malo que no hay control sobre la pagina.

Comment: ¿Seguro que el webview ocupa el 100% de la pantalla? Parece raro que el video se quede en una esquina del webview, al menos los videos de youtube ocupan el contenedor al 100%.

Comment: Si, ocupa el 100%, solo que al salir de la fullscreen ocurre esto!

Answer (score -1):

mira este ejemplo, explican como visualizar videos de youtube en una app Android

[Reproducir videos de Youtube desde tu app Android](http://androideity.com/2012/05/13/reproducir-videos-de-youtube-desde-tu-app-android/)

y la parte que dice orientación de la pantalla landscape

android:screenOrientation="landscape"